# Server with ubuntu instaled

Tags: server

I bought server on Hetzner, put ubuntu on it and use it to put some files on it. Now I download those files via android application. Everything works fine but I don't understand few things:

1. I can only get files from .../www/html folder. And I access that folder with "MyIPAddress/nameOfFile". I don't write the whole path to file, just this. All the other folders are unavailable to acces...
2. I can only access these files with http. If I write https it doesn't work.

Can anyone explain this and help me understand and change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asking very basic questions regarding Apache HTTP server configuration. I suggest that you read the Apache documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ , starting with "Getting Started" section. You should be familiar with at least basics of the configuration if you plan to set up a website.

`www/html` folder is defined by default as `DocumentRoot` in the Apache configuration (of course it can be changed). All URLs that you can access via HTTP/HTTPS are always relative to `DocumentRoot`. That's why you need to write only the file name to access the file and why you can't access folders outside `DocumentRoot`.

HTTPS is not enabled by default because you need a server certificate to connect via HTTPS. You need either to generate this certificate yourself (but then it won't be generally recognized by the browsers and requires to add exception in the browser to view the site) or purchase it from one of the generally-recognized certification authorities whose keys are built into browsers (for example, you can get a free certificate from Let's Encrypt, but ot is valid for 90 days only and must be renewed before that time if you want to keep HTTPS access to your site).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is really helpful.
So basically you want to say that if I want to have https on my server, I have to get this from some authorities (probably pay) or keep using http without paying and bothering...
Is it ok to keep using http, what downfalls do I get?

Comment: The main possible downsides of using only http: 1) if you use any form of login on your website, someone may intercept the login credentials and use someone else's account; 2) any data on your website is basically publicly available, so you should not put there any data that should remain secret, because with no encryption it can be intercepted; 3) someone can - by eg. manipulating DNS - impersonate your site so that user wanting to access your site can go to some other site without their knowledge (with https, you would usually - but not always - get a certificate warning).

Comment: Thanks for your time man, those answers are really helpful. Cheers!